# How would you design for large volume of text for an iPad?

Tags: text, ipad, quiz

I'm designing a Quiz for an iPad for English teachers and the main problem is that teachers will input large chunks of texts from many of Shakespeare plays.

I've attached pictures on how I dealt with it but any help would be nice. I'd like to have a sleek design while also ensuring the text can be accommodated for [image]

[image]

Comment: What do you dislike about your current design?

Comment: I think it's not beautiful enough.

Answer (score -2):

I may add some formating on the text on the left. Titles, subtitles, italic names... A formated text is easier to read than a flat one because it adds some visual anchors.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://ux.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://ux.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/51393)

Comment: Styling is actually use full to deal with large amount of text. So this is already an help...